# Avoiding hardcoded class name with usort

Tags: php, oop

I am implementing a sorting solution in a static method. Basically, I have:

1. A static class (`Xbanners`)
2. A static property (`Xbanners::$banners`) in this class holding an array of objects
3. A static method that sorts this array of objects depending on one parameter stored as a property on those objects ( `Xbanners::$banners[0]->priority` ).

I just use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to call the sorting method, but I have to hardcode the name of my class. How could I avoid this?

```
usort(self::$banners, 'Xbanners::' . $sortingMethod);
```

Comment: `usort(self::$banners, array('Xbanners', $sortingMethod));`

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the problem correctly, but maybe replacing `'Xbanners::'` with `'self::'` or `'static::'` (depending on your application) would help ;)

Comment: You can also try something like `usort(self::$banners, array(__CLASS__, $sortingMethod));`

Comment: @delphist: I probably didn't explain myself very well, but I am trying to avoid naming the class, as in your array('Xbanners',...). @nikic: self:: doesn't work inside usort(). @smott: __CLASS__ worked fine, please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__CLASS__` instead of hard-coded class name and an array for the callback definition à la,

```
usort( self::$banners, array( __CLASS__, $sortingMethod ) );
```

However, I would strictly recommend to not use any static members at all, but to realize your functionality in an object-oriented manner. This avoids later issues with inheritance and is a much cleaner approach (e.g. test-wise).

Comment: I know about the devils of the static classes, and I will try to redesign it when I have the time for it. Smott has pointed the __CLASS__ solution first, but if he doesn't post an answer I will happily accept yours.